# invalid use of template-name ‘Set’ without an argument list - Header and cpp files

Tags: c++, class, templates, set, arguments

I'm having a lot of problems converting my Set class into a template class. I have commented out all of the code other than the constructors and cannot get it to work. I have a header file and cpp file. Any advice?

I used the solutions from the other thread, but am unable to make it work.

Note: I only included the constructors from my cpp file since I'm working on that first.

Header file:

```
#ifndef SET_H
#define SET_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Set {
    //friend istream& operator>>( istream& in, Set& set );
    //friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& out, Set& set );

    public:
            /*bool operator+( const T& rhs );
            Set operator+( const Set& rhs );
            bool operator-( const T& rhs );
            Set operator-( Set& rhs );
            Set operator^( Set& rhs );
            bool operator==( Set& rhs );
            bool operator!=( Set& rhs );
*/
            Set();
            Set( T2 [], int, char );
            Set( const Set& );
            /*~Set() {
                    delete elements;
                    elements = NULL;
                    numElements = pSize = 0;
            }
            int length() const;
            T getElement( int ) const;
            void display();
            void checkUp();
            bool add( T );
            bool contains( T );
            bool remove( T );
            int findCell( int, T );
            */
    private:
            static const int DEFAULT_SIZE = 5;
            static const int emptyCell = -99999;
            char name;
            int pSize, numElements;
            int *elements;

};
```

cpp File:

```
#include "set.h"

template < typename T >

template <class T2> Set::Set() {
    elements = NULL;
    pSize = numElements = 0;
}

template <class T2> Set::Set( T2 array[], int ps, char nm ) {
    elements = NULL;
    pSize = numElements = 0;

    //For each member of array, we're going to add it to this
    /*
    for ( int i = 0; i < ps; i++ )
            this->add( array[ i ] );
    name = nm;
    */
}

template <class T2> Set::Set( const Set& s ) {
    elements = NULL;
    pSize = numElements = 0;

    /*For each member of the passed set, we're going to add to this
    for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ )
            this->add( s.getElement( i ) );
    */
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: 3rd time today. Why today?

Comment: I looked at the other answers, but couldn't find a clear answer to the problem I'm having. I tried the solutions but to no avail.